# parenting partner returns in google code jam error in output

Tags: python-3.x

Problem link :https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27

I got correct output for the samples but test cases are not passing. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?
My code is

```
def chores(n):
    l=[]
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
    s=[" "]*len(l)
    new=l[:]
    new=sorted(new)
    C_start=new[0][0]
    C_end=new[0][1]
    ind=l.index(new[0])
    s[ind]="C"
    C=1
    J=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        if new[i][0]>=C_end:
            ind=l.index(new[i])
            s[ind]="C"
            C_start=new[i][0]
            C_end=new[i][1]
        elif new[i][0]<C_end and J==0:
            ind=l.index(new[i])
            s[ind]="J"
            J=1
            J_start=new[i][0]
            J_end=new[i][1]
        elif new[i][0]>=J_end:
            ind=l.index(new[i])
            s[ind]="J"
            J=1
            J_start=new[i][0]
            J_end=new[i][1]
            
        else:
            return "IMPOSSIBLE"
    return "".join(s)   

tests = int(input())
ans=[]
for t in range(tests):
    n=int(input())
    ans.append(chores(n))
for i in range(0,tests):
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i+1,ans[i]))
```

Comment: Your link links to a list with several problems, can you point out which one it is?

Comment: Parenting partner returns is the problem.